# Entity Framework NullReferenceException calling ToArray() when calling SP and returned NULL in Result?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, lambda, nullreferenceexception

I have a SP that return a List of decimal that sometimes is included Null and I recive NullRefrenceException

```
var estimationLastRoleRowResults = _databaseContext.Database.SqlQuery<decimal>("SELECT RowResult FROM ES.GetEstimationItemItems(@EstimationID, 4, @RoleNumber, 1, 1, 1, 1)",
new SqlParameter("@EstimationID", item.ObjectID),
new SqlParameter("@RoleNumber", item.RoleNumber - 1)).ToArray();
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you must define nullable result for calling SP

```
var estimationLastRoleRowResults = _databaseContext.Database.SqlQuery<decimal?>("SELECT RowResult FROM ES.GetEstimationItemItems(@EstimationID, 4, @RoleNumber, 1, 1, 1, 1)",
new SqlParameter("@EstimationID", item.ObjectID),
new SqlParameter("@RoleNumber", item.RoleNumber - 1)).ToArray();
```